# Search for email containg attachment of specific file type

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search, attachments

I'd like to search for an email that contains an excel attachment. I'm using outlook.

I know I can do

> hasattachment:true

but this matches any attachment type

I've also tried,

> attachment:*.xlsx

but this doesn't work

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a little backwards, but you can do this with

```
xlsx hasattachment:true
```

Comment: This worked well. I did however get one false positive though, but it has reduced my searching time down a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I just tried this and it works well:

```
ext:xlsx
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this - it's just slightly different than what you tried and it works for me. Via [the documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/learn-to-narrow-your-search-criteria-for-better-searches-in-outlook-HA010238831.aspx).

```
attachments:.xlsx
```

Answer (score 1):

You can search for emails with (for example) Excel spreadsheet attachments by using the following:

```
filename:xlsx
```

This is documented in the [Advanced Search page](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en).