# Filter emails by attachment type "Email Attachment"

Tags: microsoft-outlook

How to filter emails in outlook 2010 for emails that has another **email attached** to it?

The question [Search for email containg attachment of specific file type](https://superuser.com/q/57405) describes how to filter for excel attachments as `xlsx hasattachment:true` or `ext:xlsx`, so how is an email type defined?

Answer (score 0):

There is no out-of-the-box way to do that. But you can go another way. What you need to do is to create a VBA macro that will iterate through your emails and set some custom property to flag that a message has email(s) attached. After that you'll be able to search your emails using this custom property.